# Eclipse の godoc コメント記述支援プラグインってありますでしょうか？

Tags: go

題名のとおりです。
ありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

GoClipseを使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。下記のリンクか、Eclipseのヘルプ内にあるEclipse Marketplaceからインストールできます。

[GoClipse | Eclipse Plugins, Bundles and Products - Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/goclipse)

また、GitHub上のWikiに記載のあるIDEやエディタの候補も、代替策として使えるかもしれませんね。

[IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins · golang/go Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
Goclipse はすでに導入しているのですがgodoc挿入のショートカットなどあるんでしょうか？